# Authentification failed when mongodump

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to dump a MongoDB database on my local machine, so I used this command according to mongodb documentation :

```
mongodump --uri="mongodb://username:password@1XX.XXX.XX.XXX:27017"
```

But my terminal returns :

```
Failed: can't create session: could not connect to server: connection() : auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-1": Authentication failed.
```

On similar posts the solution seems to be adding --authenticationDatabase=admin but it didn't work. When I try only to mongo -host 1XX.XXX.XX.XXX authentication fails as well.

Did anyone have a similar problem ?

Comment: you can try --authenticationMechanism SCRAM-SHA-256

Comment: It returns : Error: Unsupported mechanism SCRAM-SHA-256

Comment: Maybe `--authenticationDatabase` is ignored when you use `--uri`. Add `authSource=admin` to the connection string.

Comment: What does the `mongod` log file report when this connection is attempted? What versions of `mongodump` and the database are you using?